# Call_withSpeaker on setting alarm not working on samsung 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-manifest, alarmmanager

My application Call_withSpeaker on setting alarm  is working fine in android 4.2.1 micromax , 4.1.2 samsung and 2.3 motorala. *Only Problem with Samsung 4.2.2..* every thing fine but the speaker is not enable on call start only in 4.2.2 samsung  . I am Using `PhoneStateListener` and if call start once i use

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                  audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                  audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

The issue what i am facing here is Turn Speaker Phone on and off is not working properly only for Samsung 4.2.2 and samsung duas  4.1.2 
What to do.. Any idea  ?? Is it related to version or some setting in mobile ... ?? 
Thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only because In some mobile (SdkVersion 11 and above )  , its not going through `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`  and `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` and directly call `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` so in some case its fails to run your logic. Better if you check each and every callstate than you can get to know the problem.

You Have to exercise your brain little more..:)

check..It will help you

```
if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING start ");
          isPhoneCalling = true; 
          AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
          audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
          audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

        }

if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
        // active
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK..callringing");
    isPhoneCalling = true;
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
      audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

        }


if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
        // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
        // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "_callend on start ");
        Log.i("start ", "start "+callFromApp + isPhoneCalling  );    

    if (isPhoneCalling) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE_callendafter ring ");

                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 
                //Deactivate loudspeaker
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
               // Remove listener
                PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new  PhoneCallListener();
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE); 
                isPhoneCalling = false;


           }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I all ready solve this issue long back. Again thanks for your answer.